# How to Run a simple java file using batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to run my simple java file by writing an batch file,but i am not able to understand where to set the path of the file and where i can see the output.
My file Test is in my `c:/BatchFolder/Test.java`

```
Class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

and my batch file is like this...

```
@ECHO OFF
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
ECHO Compiling Java Class
javac Test.java
ECHO Compiled Java Class
ECHO Running Java Class
java BatchTest
ECHO Successfully ran Java Clas
```

How to set path of the java file which is in my `c:/BatchFolder`....

Comment: Did you look at the preview while composing your question?

Answer (score 0):

For simple solution keep the batch file in same folder. Otherwise set the class path in batch file, with the path where your class file is available and you can keep your batch file anywhere you want.